# Wordpress project redirecting to a blank index.php when i use custom templates

Tags: permalinks

I have multiple projects on my apache server that works fine, but this one i have issues with. If Permalinks are set to post name then it redirects my custom page template to index.php (which is a blank page). I've uploaded it to live and the exact same issue.

If i change the permalinks to plain, it works fine, however post name will break it.
Thoughts?

Comment: please pest your code here so I can easily help you

Comment: Which page do you wish to see?

Comment: custom page template mike wright

Comment: Use template_redirect action hook, with you conditional custom template. https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/template_redirect